# jQuery multiple file upload throwing error onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use this jquery plugin ( http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Examples ) and for some reason when i try to set the events on it I get "Function expected".  Can anyone help me?

Everything works fine, except trying to bind to the events.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=flImage.ClientID%>')[0].MultiFile(function () {
        onFileRemove: function (element, value, master_element) {
            alert('heyoooo');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the `[0]` there for? Id's must be unique, so it should always select only one. Also, using `[0]` gives you the `DOM element node` not wrapped in jquery, so you can't use `.MultiFile` if you use `[0]`

Comment: oh you almost had it, just remove the `function ()` and keep the beginning `{` curly brace

Comment: @KevinB I tried assigning $('#<%=flImage.ClientID%>')[0] to a variable and then wrapping the variable in the jQuery notation.  This got rid of the error but the event did not fire.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to supply your 'onFileRemove' function as an object parameter:

```
$('#<%=flImage.ClientID%>')[0].MultiFile({
    onFileRemove: function (element, value, master_element) {
        alert('heyoooo');
    }
});
```

This allows you to supply multiple functions as parameters and all function parameters are optional.

Comment: This removes the error, but I still am not getting an alert when the event is supposed to fire

Comment: if you are trying to select the first element in a set of matched elements, you might want to do it this way instead: `$('#<%=flImage.ClientID%>').first().MultiFile....`